# XML to JSON producing undesired results

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

I'm using the `org.json` library, as seen below, to convert from XML to JSON

> ```
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.json</groupId>
>       <artifactId>json</artifactId>
>       <version>20160212</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

*A simple test case shows the problem I am having, see below: -*

I have the following XML

```
<record>
  <name>A108B</name>
</record>
```

which in turn, produces

```
{"record": { "id": "A108B" }}
```

Great! The problem occurs if `id` is **1111**

Using the following code

```
XML.toJSONObject(xml...)
```

I get

```
{"record": { "name": 1111 }}
```

I'd actually prefer to keep the values as all strings, i.e. user identifiers. I don't want the output changing depending on whether the identifier happens to not have a character in it.

Is there any way I can force org.json to do this? I can probably fork the code and make a change for myself but I would expect that this is a problem someone else has come across and has a solution for.

Comment: The tool at http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.VwFtQBMrJmB seems to convert how I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick, I had to override the `nextValue` of JSONTokener.

```
    String xml = "<test>111</test>";
    JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
    JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json.toString()) {
        public Object nextValue() throws JSONException {
            Object nextValue = super.nextValue();
            if (nextValue instanceof Number) {
                Number value = (Number) nextValue;
                return value.toString();
            }
            return nextValue;
        }
    };
    json = new JSONObject(tokener);
    System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output: `{"test":"111"}`

Answer (score 0):

`XML.toJSONObject(...)` internally calls `static Object stringToValue(String string)` which will *always* try to convert the value to `Boolean`, `JSONObject.Null`, `Long` and `Double` first, and return a `String` only when all conversion attempts fail. There seems to be no (easy) way around this.

Instead of forking or doing some reflection magic, you can simply convert the value when reading:

```
JSONObject rec = json.getJSONObject("record");
String name = rec
                .get("name")
                .toString();

// optionally put the string value back into your JSON:
rec.put("name", name);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the test case I made simplifies the xml/json, greatly. If I were to traverse the entire hierarchy, I would probably be better writing my own xml to json converter

Comment: @chrisw I guess then your best option will be to copy the `XML` utility class and replace the `static Object stringToValue(String string)` method with your own implementation.